# Can not insert new Google Calendar Event via the ruby API, reminder error

Tags: ruby, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

```
  event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
    "summary":"appointment",
    "description":"placeholder",
    "start": {
     "date_time":'2016-05-28T08:00:00',
     "time_zone":'Europe/Brussels',
    },
    "end": {
     "date_time":'2016-05-28T09:00:00',
     "time_zone":'Europe/Brussels',
    },
    'reminders': {
     'useDefault': false,
     'overrides': [
       {'minutes': 840, 'method': 'popup'}
     ]
    },  
    "color_id": "11"
  })
  result = service.insert_event('primary', event)
```

I am trying to insert a calendar event via the ruby API. This code gives the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/google-api-client-0.9.6/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:211:in `check_status': cannotUseDefaultRemindersAndSpecifyOverride: Cannot specify both default reminders and overrides at the same time. (Google::Apis::ClientError)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try replacing your existing hash in overrides by the following ?   {method' => 'popup', 'minutes: 840},

Comment: That is the example used in the google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples). You notice right away that the quotation marks are incorrect, but when corrected: `{'method' => 'popup', 'minutes': 840}`, it results in the same error.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

It may be a little late but I was having the same problem and I found a workaround.

Create the `event` without the `reminders`. Once you have the `event` created with the initializer set the reminders like this:

```
event.reminders = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event::Reminders.new(
    use_default: false,
    overrides: [
      Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventReminder.new(reminder_method:"popup", minutes: reminder_minutes),
      Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventReminder.new(reminder_method:"email", minutes: reminder_minutes)
    ]
  )
```

That is working for me!